# Three-level pom (company - project - module) - problems with module project(s)

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I am using Eclipse Indigo with m2e (which connects to an external binary of Maven 3.0.3).

Right now, the intended structure of my application is as follows:

```
Company-parent
--Project-parent
----Module1
----Module2
----ModuleN
```

I set up my poms such that Company-parent is the project of Project-parent, and Project-parent is the parent of all of the modules. The company-parent and the project-parent seem to be ok. Both are of packaging type POM.

The third level is where I start to encounter problems. I get a variety of maven errors, and all kinds of weird behavior, even with the simplest of module projects defined.

Company parent:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.scoresecret</groupId>
  <artifactId>scs-global-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>
```

Project parent:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>scs-global-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.scoresecret</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>scs-model-parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.scoresecret.model</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>scs-model-core</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Module pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>scs-model-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.scoresecret.model</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>scs-model-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I can't do "Maven -> Update Project Configuration", because when I do, I get this error:

```
Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 in https://my.archiva.location/archiva/repository/internal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of scs.internal has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /scs-model-core line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
```

Some other errors I'm receiving:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3 pom.xml /scs-model-core line 1  Maven Build Problem
```

Also receiving an error about m2e ignoring one of my plugin goals (from the company level pom) within the module. Am I missing something obvious here? Help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that my local repo contained files which ended with the extention ".lastUpdated" ... this was because I was having problems with authentication when I tried encrypting my maven passwords, so it wasn't downloading the dependencies. I deleted those files and simply ran "Maven > Update Dependencies" and it worked no problem, downloading the missing resources from my artifact repository.

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't have the artifacts located like you described in a directory structure.

```
+-- Company-parent (pom.xml)
      +-- Project-parent (pom.xml)
            +----Module1 (pom.xml)
            +----Module2 (pom.xml)
            +----ModuleN (pom.xml)
```

To make a real good use of you company-parent (pom.xml) it should be helt into a separated area in version control and released separately in your repository manager (nexus, artifactory, archiva...). This will result in the following structure:

```
+-- Company-parent (pom.xml) (Separate Project)
```

The company-parent should be released as often as needed via the release-plugin. Lets assume we have released version 1.0 of the company-parent. The reason to have it separated is, cause the company-parent is used by many projects and not only by a single project.

and the real projects should be put into a separate folder (also in version control):

```
+-- Project-parent (pom.xml)
     +----Module1 (pom.xml)
     +----Module2 (pom.xml)
     +----ModuleN (pom.xml)
```

So to use the company-parent in your project the project-parent has to look like:

```xml
<project....>
 <modelVersion>4.0...</modelVersion>

<parent>
  <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.company.base</groupId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<groupId>com.company.project1</groupId>
<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<dependencyManagement>
 <!-- Project specific dependencies -->
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Project specific plugins. Better use them of the company pom -->
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
<modules>
  <module>module1</module>
  <module>module2</module>
  <module>moduleN</module>
</modules>
..
```

Now let us  take a look into a module which should look like this:

```xml
<project....>
 <modelVersion>4.0...</modelVersion>

<parent>
  <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.company.project1</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<artifactId>module1</artifactId>

<dependencies>...</dependencies>
<build>..</build>
```

Comment: It is how you described, I just had it listed as such to show the hierarchy. The company parent is in it's own area in scm, it's own workspace in eclipse, and is resolved through my artifact (and then local) repo

Comment: But your company pom should be in a separate location in version control cause it's an independent artifact. Use a repository manager (nexus, artifactory or achiva).

Comment: +1 For highlighting the importance of releasing a corporate POM into a corporate repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the parent pom with explicit path:

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>scs-model-parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.scoresecret.model</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relateivePath>
</parent>
```

Otherwise, you need to reinstall the parent pom into the repository every time you change it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, on why I should reference the project-parent with relativePath? Keep in mind, I am not using a flat project structure, the model-core project is a folder within the model-parent.

Comment: If you don't do so, the pom will be retrieved from repo.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Makes very logical sense. I'm starting to get this maven thing and it feels great!! thank you!!

Comment: I vastly prefer [khmarbaise's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9875632/474189), as it highlights how important it is to deploy a corporate POM into a corporate repository.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maven isn't able to download a plugin (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3) from the repository https://my.archiva.location/archiva/repository/internal

*Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 in https://my.archiva.location/archiva/repository/internal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of scs.internal has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /scs-model-core line 1  Maven Configuration Problem*

If you browse to this URL in a browser, does it exist? I see it's using https - do you need a client cert or some form of basic auth credentials to access this url?

What are your current settings in your .m2/settings.xml show for repositories? Are you behind a company firewall or not connected to the internet which is forcing you to connect to a non-standard maven central repository?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it helped me solve the problem. Posting my own answer right now.